# How to show progress dialog over my custom dialog?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a custom dialog which is opened and there is some task for which I have to show my progress dialog over it. But I guess progress dialog is showing below my custom dialog. Here is the code I tried

#### My progress dialog code

KProgressHUD is the third party library

```
private void progressDialog() {
    kProgressHUD = new KProgressHUD(getActivity());
    if (!kProgressHUD.isShowing()) {
        kProgressHUD.setStyle(KProgressHUD.Style.SPIN_INDETERMINATE)
                .setLabel("Please wait")
                .setCancellable(false)
                .setAnimationSpeed(2)
                .setDimAmount(0.5f)
                .show();
    }
}
```

#### My Custom dialog code

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(consumerHomeActivity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_select_vendor);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
    wlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);

    loadVendorsListFromFirebaseDB(dialog, bookingType);
    dialog.show();
```

#### Method in which I am calling progress dialog method

```
private void loadVendorsListFromFirebaseDB(final Dialog dialog, final String bookingType) {

    progressDialog();

    final ArrayList<VendorsList> arrayListVendorsList = new ArrayList<>();
    final ListView vendorsListLv = dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_select_vendor_list_lv);

    DatabaseReference databaseReferenceVendorsList = firebaseDatabase.getReference("vendorsList");

    databaseReferenceVendorsList.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            arrayListVendorsList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String vendorEmailId = postSnapshot.getKey();
                String vendorName = postSnapshot.child("vendorName").getValue(String.class);

                VendorsList vendorsList = new VendorsList();
                vendorsList.setVendorEmailID(vendorEmailId);
                vendorsList.setVendorName(vendorName);

                arrayListVendorsList.add(vendorsList);

            }

            if (arrayListVendorsList.size() == 0) {
                StaticMethods.customSnackBar(consumerHomeActivity.parentLayout, "Sorry, no vendors available right now",
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark),
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.error_orange), 3000);
            }

            vendorsListAdapter = new VendorsListAdapter(consumerHomeActivity, arrayListVendorsList);
            vendorsListLv.setAdapter(vendorsListAdapter);

            dismissDialog();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: in which type of dialog you want to show and why use special library for that?

Comment: I want to show Progress Dialog(KProgressHUD) over my custom dialog. I have used this special library as it is little fancy and easy to manage.

Comment: Well I don't know who has downvoted my question. But just let me know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just swipe below lines

```
loadVendorsListFromFirebaseDB(dialog, bookingType);
dialog.show();
```

to

```
dialog.show();
loadVendorsListFromFirebaseDB(dialog, bookingType);
```

this is because you were showing dialog after the progressdialog is shown

Comment: Thanks brother, your solution worked. Cannot upvote your answer as I dont have enough reputations for it. Sorry

Comment: Already up-voted this answer but as my reputation is less. It will not be displayed publicly

Answer (score 0):

You are showing progess dialog before showing Dialog.Use it as

```
dialog.show();
loadVendorsListFromFirebaseDB(dialog, bookingType);
```

As suggestion Use [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) instead of Dialog. Its a fragment with dialog appearance and  more Suitable for your need .

Answer (score 0):

You are loading your list of data first and after showing your custom dialog.  Therefore your progress dialog does not show over custom dialog.

Please change your code as below to show first custom dialog and after load your list of data.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(consumerHomeActivity);

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_select_vendor);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
wlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
window.setAttributes(wlp);

dialog.show();
loadVendorsListFromFirebaseDB(dialog, bookingType);
```